# I want to create a jar file for maven project using cli where I have mentioned war plugin in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, war

Code : https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war/blob/master/pom.xml

Here in POM.XML file there is war which is as required.

Now, I am building project using below CLI commands

mvn clean
mvn install -Dpackaging = jar

Output required to get jar file for a project whereas it is creating the war file due to given war plugin in pom.xml.

Any idea on how can we generate jar file by using only cli , not updating the pom.xml from the given link.

Comment: that is not how maven works, jar and war formats have quite different porposes. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.